# Maven and tool.jar not found

Tags: java, maven, deployment, alexa-skills-kit

I'm tring to develop an alexa skill in java and when I launch the command:
mvn assembly:assembly -DdescriptorId=jar-with-dependencies package
on Airplane Facts sample the prompt return this error:
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project airplanefacts: Fatal error compiling: tools.jar not found: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_191..\lib\tools.jar ->

Someone can help me?
I tried to change PC, reinstall different versions of JDK and different versions of maven but nothing change ...

Comment: The `tools.jar` file is located in the JDK, not the JRE, it appears that you're executing this with the JRE/have some path configured to load the `tools.jar` from the JRE instead of JDK

Comment: thank you @Mark for your answer, but do you know how I can fix this problem?change anything to do that ...

Comment: If you execute `echo %JAVA_HOME%` in CMD on windows, what path does it display? For me the path ends with `jdk1.8.0_181`, if this is JRE for you setting this correctly probably will fix your issue

Comment: Interesting ... my pronpt print: %JAVA_HOME%

Comment: Thank you @Mark! I found that I should check the path variable and not the JAVA_HOME! Now it works correctly!